# Reverse words cant seem to find them all

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

One thing I am trying to do is find words that are reversed and are greater or equal to 5 characters, for the following code I have it finds palindrome and any word that is the same backwards

However, I cannot figure out how to get it find 'Damon' or 'nomad'

I have tried using `sorted()` to get anagrams but unable to implement it.

```
import sys

word = []

backword = []

def main():
    for lines in sys.stdin:
        word.append(lines.strip())

    for element in word:
        if len(element.lower()) >= 5 and element.lower() == element[::-1].lower():  
                backword.append(element)        
    print(backword)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit - Thank you for your solutions I have to find another way that does it fast...

Comment: Why would it find `Damon` or `nomad`, they are not palindromes?

Comment: I need to find words in a list, and occur reversed and occur in the list

Comment: By definition their reverse is in the list of words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you're looking for any word in a list that is the reverse of another word in the list? In that case you have a few options.

Case 1: You can precompute the list of reversed characters like so:

```
reversed = [element[::-1].lower() for element in word if len(element) >= 5]
backword = [element for element in word if element.lower() in reversed]
```

Making a map may also be faster:

```
reversed = map(lambda s: s.lower()[::-1], word)
backword = [element for element in word if element.lower() in reversed]
```

Case 2: You can reverse and check each time like so:

```
backword = [element for element in word if element[::-1] in word]
```

In the case that you have capitalized words that you haven't filtered out:

```
backword = [element for element in word if element[::-1] in word or element[::-1].lower().capitalize() in word]
```

In the case where you have mixed casing in `word` you should go with case 1 as you can precompute both values with reduced complexity due to the conditions in place.

Comment: Your solution case 1 works perfectly however due to requirements for the problem I am attempting it is slow..  Thank you for your solutions

Comment: You can also do a `map`, I added that to the end of case 1. Should be somewhat faster as lists aren't very efficient

Comment: I made a little adjustment to your reversed instead of it having '[]' I changed it to {} which made it print the desired output immediately.

Comment: Ah yes, a set or dictionary based solution will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Using the structure you have provided, this would work:

```
words = ['Damon', 'test', 'word', 'nomad']

reverse = []
words_set = set(map(str.lower, words))

for element in words:
    if len(element.lower()) >= 5 and element.lower()[::-1] in words_set:
        reverse.append(element)

print(reverse)

# ['Damon', 'nomad']
```